# Allow iOS App Write To MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, ios, database, post

**Very simply** - I'm developing an iOS application which will give the user the opportunity to write an application-created integer to a MySql Database.

This integer corresponds to the user's success with the app. From a user-perspective, the higher the integer value the better. I want to highlight at this point, it's **not** a game as such, and I'm not looking to implement the GameCenter feature/highscores etc.

So far I've looked at implementing a PHP Web Service, that will receive a 'POST' from the iOS device. This 'POST' would contain the int value being written to the database.

My questions are as follows-

1) Is this the best approach to writing a integer value to a web-hosted database?

2) How can I secure this approach so that dummy POST's cannot be sent to my web service or **only allow iOS device's** to write to the database.

My worry is that someone will find out the URL of my web service, and start sending POST data which hasn't been generated by the iOS device.

Any feedback would be great, thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394848/how-do-i-only-allow-access-to-my-mysql-database-from-my-ios-app-using-webapp-a

Comment: Thank you, that looks like what I'm after!